# Confusions about cone definition in category.

Tags: category-theory, definition

I am new to category theory.

The definition of "cone" in Wiki:

Let $F : J \to C$ be a diagram in $C$.

Let $N$ be an object of $C$. A cone from $N$ to $F$ is a family of morphisms
$$
\psi _{X}\colon N\to F(X)\,
$$
for each object $X$ of $J$, such that for every morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $J$ the following diagram commutes:

[image]

The most confusion part is "a family of morphisms"

My questions are:

1. If one object $Y$ of $J$, but there is no morphisms from $N$ to $F(Y)$, so
   $N \to F(Y)$ simply do not exist in the cone?  Could this conclusion be changed if $f : X \to Y$ do exist in $J$ ?
2. If one object $Z$ of $J$, but there are more than 1 morphisms from $N$ to $F(Z)$. So in this case, should we pick 1 morphism from all the morphisms from $N$ to $F(Z)$, according to  the commutative diagram ? But what if none of those morphisms could satisfy the commutative diagram , so none of those morphisms in the cone ?  Could this conclusion be changed if $f : X \to Z$ do exist in $J$ ?
3. It seems that a cone is closely related to $J$.  Is it right to say "different $J_1, J_2$ may have different cone from $N$ ? or even did not exist a cone " ?

Thank you ! Any examples of cone is much appreciated!

Comment: One way to see the cone definition, particularly illuminating for me, is at [this link](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/limits-and-colimits-part-2).

Comment: @azifoo Thank you very much, very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write such a cone as $\psi : N \to F$. Notice that it's the same as a natural transformation / morphism of functors $\psi : \Delta(N) \to F$, where $\Delta(N)$ denotes the constant functor with value $N$.

1. If there is some object $Y \in J$ such that no morphism $N \to F(Y)$ exists, this implies that there is no cone $N \to F$. Your question "Could this conclusion be changed ..." is unclear.
2. Certainly there can be any number of morphisms $N \to F(Z)$. A cone just picks one of these morphisms, for every object $Z$ in the index category $J$. And not just that: the choices need to be "compatible", meaning that the mentioned diagrams commute. And yes, this is not always possible. Again, your question "Could this conclusion be changed ..." is unclear.
3. Of course the whole definition depends on $J$ in a very important way. Just look at some examples and compare the notions of cones: $J = ( \bullet ~~~ \bullet)$ yields a binary product cone, $J = (\bullet \rightarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet)$ yields a pullback cone, $J = (~)$ yields an empty cone. I don't know if this is what you are after, but every functor $J_2 \to J_1$ induces for every cone $J_1$-shaped cone a $J_2$-shaped cone, simply by precomposing the diagram with that functor.

Comment: So in a cone, between the vertex  $N$ and a given object  $X$, 
 there must be only 1 or 0 morphism in the cone,  no matter how many morphisms between them in the category?

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give me some category textbook for beginners?

Comment: 1) One morphism. 2) Tom Leinster, Basic Category Theory. https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375 or https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/basic-category-theory/A72533879BBC7BD956CC415777B7DA99

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful!